# unquote string as variable in pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to remove duplicate rows from a dataframe, for specific columns only. That can be obtained with `distinct`:

```
data <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2, 2), b = c(3, 3, 3, 4), z = c(5,4,5,5))
filtered_data <- data %>% distinct(a, b, .keep_all = T)
dim(filtered_data)  
# [1] 3 3
```

This is (almost) what I need. Yet, my problem is that the columnnames I need to use with `distinct` will change. So I have a string `gen` that contains the names of the columns I want to use for with the `distinct` function. They need to get unquoted to be usefull in the pipe. I found suggestions to use `as.name()` or `eval(parse())`. This however gives me a different result:

```
gen <- c("a", "b")
filtered_data <- data %>% distinct(eval(parse(text = gen)), .keep_all = T)
dim(filtered_data)  
# [1] 2 4
```

The `eval` seems to do something funny with the amount of times the data is filtered. (and, adds an extra column. I could live with that, though...) So, how to obtain a similar result, as if I had used `a,b`, but by using a variable instead?

**additional information**
I actually obtain `gen` by reading the columnnames of a dataframe: `gen <- colnames(data)[1:2]`. The solution suggested by @gymbrane would be perfect, if I had a way to transform the `gen` to `c(a, b)`. The whole point is to avoid hardcoding the columnames. I tried things like `gen <- noquotes(gen)`, which does not give an error in the `rm_dup_rows` function suggested below, but it does give a different result, giving the same sort of repeated filtering as I started with...

**fixed**
I think I got it working. It might be unelegant, and I'm not sure if every step is necessary for the result, but it seems to work by combining the function provided by @gymbrane below with `ensym` and `quos` in a forloop while adding to a list <s>in `GlobalEnv`</s> (edit: GlobalEnv isn't necessary):

```
unquote_string <- function(string) {
  out <- list()
  i <- 1
  for (s in string) {
    t <- ensym(s)
    out[i] <-dplyr::quos(!!t)
    i <- i+1
  }
return(out)
}
gen_quo <- unquote_string(gen)
filtered_data <- rm_dup_rows(data, gen_quo)
dim(filtered_data)
# [1] 3 3
```

Comment: is the amount of columns used for the distinct always 2? since eval only gives one output, an (ugly) workaround for your example case could be: `distinct(eval(parse(text=gen[1])),eval(parse(text=gen[2])), .keep_all = T)`. But hopefully someone shows up with a more elegant and robust solution

Comment: No, the columns aren't always 2. They fluctuate between something like 5 and 20...

Comment: `unquote_string` is a clever solution. I would suggest renaming your helper function to something like `unqoute_charvec` to be a bit more descriptive about what it does.  Not that it probably matters but it would be more `R` like to use `lapply` instead of a `for` loop and it will be a bit more efficient. Something like
    `unquote_charvec <- function(x){
      lapply(X = x, FUN = function(i){
        t = rlang::ensym(i)
        quo(!!t)
      })
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a function and using [quosures](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) . Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for...

```
rm_dup_rows <- function(data, ...){
  vars = dplyr::quos(...)
  data %>% distinct(!!! vars, .keep_all = T)
}
```

I believe this returns what you are asking for

```
rm_dup_rows(data = data, a, b)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     b     z
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     3     5
    2     3     5
    2     4     5


rm_dup_rows(data, b, z)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
a     b     z
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     3     5
    1     3     4
    2     4     5
```

## Additional

You could modify `rm_dup_rows` just slightly and construct and your vector with `quos`. Something like this...

```
rm_dup_rows <- function(data, vars){
  data %>% distinct(!!! vars, .keep_all = T)
}

# quos your column name vector
gen <- quos(a,z)

rm_dup_rows(data, gen)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     b     z
 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
   1     3     5
   1     3     4
   2     3     5
```

Comment: That seems to get in the direction. The problem is, however, that I want to avoid to supply the columnnames one by one: ```rm_dup_rows(data, gen)``` would be perfect, but the string ```gen```  containing the columnnames doesn't get unquoted properly... However, I think that using quosures is probably the right direction.

Comment: I added the Additional section to the answer, which does what you are looking for, I believe.

Comment: That would be almost perfect, if I had a workaround to transform gen to an unquoted string like you did with quos. I produce gen by collecting ```colnames()```, and it would only relocate the problem if I had to manually create strings with ```quos()```. I tried things like ```gen <- quos(noquote(gen))```, but that produces the same sort of overfiltering I started with...

Comment: When combined with the ```unquote-string``` function I added to my question, this gives an identical outcome to spelling out all variables by hand.